# The meaning of the word 切り整える

Tags: words

I can't find anything about 切り整える. I found it in this definition for 髪型:

> 結ったり，切り整えたりして仕上げた髪の恰好。髪のかたち。ヘア-スタイル。

I know that 整える means "to put something in order", but what does it mean with 切り in front of it? All I could find was that 切り整える means "to cut and prepare stones" which I don't think makes sense here.

Does anyone know its meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

切り整える just means *to cut and put in order*. What is put in order is ragged edge of the hairs (I'm not sure the term is appropriate).

In hair cutting context, 整える does not add so much substantial meaning, but the meaning of 切り整える (or [切り揃える](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%88%87%E3%82%8A%E6%8F%83%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B/#jn-58332) which is synonymous) is cutting a bunch of hair to the same length. (I do not mean it implies one length hair style, but cutting the hairs so that no hair sticks out too much.)

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand. Maybe a better term would be "messy hairtips" but I'm not sure either.